# How to represent the name of a variable in batches in python?

Tags: python, list

I have many `lists` ,which are named like `a+str(i)`, such as `a0`. I want to add the two adjacent ones in turn.

```
a0=['a']
a1=['k']
a2=['e','a']
a3=['k','e']

a0=a0+a1
a1=a1+a2
a2=a2+a3
```

I want to know whether there are a way to represent the name of the `list` in batches in python.

I expect to use a `for` loop to express.

`Expected:`

```
for i in range(1,4):
    ai= ai + a(i-1)
```

Comment: Don't do that, use a dict instead.

Comment: A `dict`? How to do it?

Comment: You should make `a` a list of lists instead if the indexes are sequential: `a = [[i + 1] for i in range(4)]`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Comment: @StephenRauch Exactly, I don't think that's a duplicate but that blhsing's comment is the answer (that doesn't exclude the possibility that this is a duplicate of another question though).

Comment: Why can't you just use a list for the original values, where `i` is the index, e.g. `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]`?  In this case, `a[2]` would equal 3. You could use a generator to modify the original values.

Comment: @a_guest, the dict will accommodate the entirety of the OPs listed code. A list made be more appropriate but a dict will also work.